# Custom metric group in flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I tried custome metric group in flink and implemented "open and "map" method but unable to update group name from map method.

Comment: Why would you like to change the name? Perhaps there's another way to achieve the same end result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to change the name of a `MetricGroup`. The name is set when the group is created (which is typically done in the `open` method of a `RichFunction`), and remains fixed.